# Control the number of digits in the power of scientific notation (e.g. e-3 instead of e-03)

Tags: r

I can see ways to control the number of decimals printed in scientific notation. But is there a way to control the digits in the power?

```
> num = -0.000173929
> num
[1] -0.000173929
> format(num, scientific=T)
[1] "-1.73929e-04"
> format(num, digits=2, scientific=T)
[1] "-1.7e-04"
```

I want the value to print as follows.

```
-1.7e-4
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple regex,

```
gsub('0','',format(num, digits=2, scientific=TRUE))
#[1] "-1.7e-4"
```

Comment: You need to require the 0 to follow the sign after the `e`, or you'll get errors on things like `num = 1e100`:  `gsub('0', '', format(num, digits=2, scientific=TRUE))` gives `[1] "1e+1"`.

Comment: Thank you for the warning. So I used `gsub('e-0','e-',format(num, digits=2, scientific=TRUE))`